# Foreach() value is set, after value disappears

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to add a new key to an existing numerical indexed array using a foreach() loop.
I wrote this piece of code:

```
foreach($new['WidgetInstanceSetting'] as $row){
        $row['random_key'] = $this->__str_rand(32, 'alphanum'); 
        debug($row);
    }
    debug($new);
```

The first debug() works as I expected: the 'random_key' is created in the $new array.
Now, the problem is that the second debug() shows the $new array, but **without** the newly added key.
Why is this happening? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$row` ends up being a copy in the scope of the `foreach` block, so you really are modifying a copy of it and not what's in the original array at all.

Stick a `&` in your `foreach` to modify the `$row` array within your `$new` array by reference:

```
foreach($new['WidgetInstanceSetting'] as &$row){
```

And as user576875 says, delete the reference to `$row` in case you use that variable again to avoid unwanted behavior, because PHP leaves it around:

```
foreach($new['WidgetInstanceSetting'] as &$row){
    $row['random_key'] = $this->__str_rand(32, 'alphanum'); 
    debug($row);
}
unset($row);
debug($new);
```

Comment: and don't forget do unset the reference after foreach(), or you will get odd bugs

Comment: Thanks. One more thing: how to unset the reference?

Comment: Oh, I got it. I thought it was something more difficult. Thank you very much again for clarifying this problem for me :) .

Answer (score 5):

Use the `&` to get a by reference value that you can change.

```
foreach($new['WidgetInstanceSetting'] as &$row){
        $row['random_key'] = $this->__str_rand(32, 'alphanum'); 
        debug($row);
    }
    debug($new);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the element ***by reference*** if you want to modify if within the array, as follows:

```
foreach($new['WidgetInstanceSetting'] as &$row) {
    $row['random_key'] = $this->__str_rand(32, 'alphanum'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not creating random_key in $new array you are creating it in $row